# Qual a função DispatcherServlet no Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Qual a finalidade dele? é recomendado usar o spring-boot para fazer todas configurações xml do spring automaticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Servlet]

O trabalho do `DispatcherServlet` é pegar uma URI requisitada e encontrar a combinação certa do manipulador (geralmente métodos nas classes controladoras) e views (geralmente JSPs) que combinam para o formulário da página ou recurso suposto ser encontrado naquela localização.

Eu posso ter :

- um arquivo `/WEB-INF/jsp/pages/Home.jsp`.
- um método na classe

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value="/pages/Home.html")
  private ModelMap buildHome() {
      return somestuff;
  }
  ```

O Dispatcher Servlet é o pedaço que "sabe" chamar o método quando o navegador requisita a página, combina os resultados com o arquivo JSP e gera um documento HTML.

Referências e resposta completa em Inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769467/what-is-dispatcher-servlet-in-spring/2769523#2769523

Documentação:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno